# protected $_canRefund = false;

Tags: magento

I want to know more about this variable in magento core\Mage\Paygate\Model\Payflow\Pro.php
protected $_canRefund = false;

I think keeping it disabled will not process online refund and it should be true to enable online refunding.

What my problem is I am trying to do an offline refund in magento 1.3.2.4 but amount is appearing in the column online refunded when it should be collected in column offline refunded.

I want to generate credit memo in offline mode and do payment outside magento. note there is no two different methods for credit memo as in newer versions.

Hope I explained it well.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe (don't hold me to it) that the canRefund is a definable state for locking the refund process on a particular order.

I.e if you have refunded once it won't let you do it again.

I don't think this has any impact on the online/offline refund options at least.

I don't have an old version of Magento to reference it against as the Payflow model directory doesn't exist on 1.6.2.0 (version I work on!).

Comment: in newer version also this variable is there but more inheritance is there. core\Mage\Paypal\Model\Payflowpro.php                     protected $_canRefund               = true;       And I think it is to control an online refund on payment class.